# sum of setof in prolog

Tags: sum, prolog, set

I have this predicate to get the sum of the length of all borders of a country. I could solve it with findall but I have to use setof. My facts look like this:

```
borders(sweden,finland,586).
borders(norway,sweden,1619).
```

My code

```
circumference(C, Country) :-
    findall(X, ( borders(Country, _, X) ; borders(_, Country, X)), Kms),
    sum_list(Kms, C).
```

Comment: Just put in the correct existential variables when switching from findall to setof.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the sum using `bagof` directly, all you can do is make a list and then sum that list (but you knew that already). In SWI-Prolog there is [library(aggregate)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) that does the bagging and the summing for you. With the facts you have, you would write:

```
?- aggregate(sum(X), Y^( borders(Y, sweden, X) ; borders(sweden, Y, X) ), Circumference).
Circumference = 2205.
```

If you instead must obey the whims of your instructor and type "bagof" yourself, or if you are not allowed to use a modern, open source, comprehensive Prolog implementation, you can use the same approach with `bagof` and manually build the list before summing it:

```
?- bagof(X, Y^( borders(Y, sweden, X) ; borders(sweden, Y, X) ), Borders).
Borders = [1619, 586].
```

For reasons that are lost in the mists of time the funny thing with the `Var^Goal` that you see in both `aggregate` and `bagof` is called "existentially qualifying the variables in *Goal*". You might also read that "`^` prevents binding *Var* in *Goal*". I cannot explain what this really means.

Comment: ` I cannot explain what this really means.` You should get a copy of the ISO Prolog standard Part 1 then. $$

Comment: @GuyCoder I strongly suspect that even if I read that (I will not), I will still cannot explain it. I leave such explanations to more cleverer people than I.

Comment: I don't think `Var^Goal` prevents binding of `Var` in `Goal`. the `Var` can still get bound in (instantiated by) `Goal`, it just won't be taken into account for the purposes of grouping the results gotten by backtracking on `Goal`, into the groups produced by `bagof` on *its* backtracking. it is *as if* we only care whether a successful instantiation of `Var` *exists*, and do not care about its value (even though that value will appear in the results, if it is indeed instantiated by `Goal`). that's how I explain this thing to myself anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
circumference(Z, Country) :- setof(X, Q^(borders(Q,Country,X);borders(Country,Q,X)),Border),
                    sum_list(Border,Z).


% Adds the numbers in a list. 
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], Sum) :-
   sum_list(T, Rest),
   Sum is H + Rest.
```